# How to exctract a part of a url in this case?

Tags: python, regex, string

So I need a way to extract file names from public dropbox urls, without using the API, I've concluded that all sharing links in Dropbox are made like this :

```
dropbox.com/s/{random alphanemucric string}/{file name}
```

For example I have this link :

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbyuft7zscqzgbs/checklist%281%29.pdf?dl=0
```

How can I extract the "checklist%281%29.pdf" part from this url, I don't have any idea how I would make my regex to extract this .

Comment: `random_string, file_name = URL.split("/")[-2:]` prehaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
>>> name = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbyuft7zscqzgbs/checklist%281%29.pdf?dl=0'
>>> name.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
'checklist%281%29.pdf'
```

The `split("/")[-1]` takes everything after the last slash, and the `split('?')[0]` removes parameters, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`urlparse.urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit),

```
import os
import urlparse 

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbyuft7zscqzgbs/checklist%281%29.pdf?dl=0'

path = urlparse.urlsplit(url).path  # /s/sbyuft7zscqzgbs/checklist%281%29.pdf
filename = os.path.basename(path)   # checklist%281%29.pdf
```

---

Previous answer,

```
import os

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbyuft7zscqzgbs/checklist%281%29.pdf?dl=0'
filename = os.path.basename(url).replace('?dl=0', '')

print(filename) # Output: checklist%281%29.pdf
```